# How to load obj file to PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I'm trying to load .obj file to PyOpenGL and pygame referring to http://www.pygame.org/wiki/OBJFileLoader and https://github.com/yarolig/OBJFileLoader

I've tried to change the perspective and do translation but the object can't be seen

here is what i've come so far

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from objloader import *


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    display = (1000,600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

    gluPerspective(90, (display[0]/display[1]), 1, 100)

    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -10)

    # import file
    model = OBJ('model.obj')

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        
        # draw model
        glPushMatrix()
        glTranslatef(10, 10, 10)
        model.render()
        glPopMatrix()
        
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL has different current matrices, see [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml). Each vertex coordinate is transformed by the model view matrix and the projection matrix.
I recommend to set the projection matrix to the current `GL_PROJECTION` and the view matrix to the current `GL_MODELVIEW`:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # [...]

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION) # <---- specify projection matrix
    gluPerspective(90, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 100)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)  # <---- specify model view matrix
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
```

Anyway you have to remove the model transformation, because the model transformation moves the object out of the [Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) and causes that the model is clipped:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # [...]

    while True:
        # [...]

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        
        # draw model
        glPushMatrix()
        #glTranslatef(10, 10, 10) <--- DELETE
        model.render()
        glPopMatrix()
```

Note, the [Wavefront OBJ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_OBJ) loader requires a *.obj* and a *.mtl* file to load the model correctly.